# Since Upgrading NFS and Ubuntu to 14.04, All NFS Mounts Are Failing

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

Since upgrading my Ubuntu Machine, all my NFS mounts are hanging. I checked the syslog, and I'm seeing this now:

```
Sep 29 04:29:10 ip-10-10-10-10 kernel: [ 9589.594814] RPC: AUTH_GSS upcall failed. Please check user daemon is running.
```

All other methods of debugging NFS still show it up and running (telnet, rpcinfo, etc). What is the AUTH_GSS service and why does it need to be running? I've been running around on Google, but I can't see any reason why it wouldn't already be going.

** UPDATE **

In addition to this, I'm now seeing the following on the server:

```
Sep 29 05:55:12 ip-10-10-10-10 rpc.gssd[860]: ERROR: can't open /run/rpc_pipefs/gssd/clntXX/info: No such file or directory
Sep 29 05:55:12 ip-10-10-10-10 rpc.gssd[860]: ERROR: failed to read service info
```

** FURTHER DEBUGGING **

To be clear, it's absolutely running, and accepting connections from the client machine. I'm able to telnet over to 111 and 2049 from the client machine with no issue.

Comment: how did you solve this in the end?

Answer (score 7):

[GSSAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Security_Services_Application_Program_Interface) or the Generic Security Services Application Programming Interface is used by NFS (versions 3 and 4) when using Kerberos for authentication and encryption.

The ubuntu config file `/etc/default/nfs-common` has a few lines about this:

```
# Do you want to start the gssd daemon? It is required for Kerberos mounts.
NEED_GSSD=
```

Either configure Kerberos and GSS or make sure you don't use them.

There's a related [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1270445) on launchpad that suggests either setting `NEED_GSSD=yes` or disabling GSS by blacklisting the `rpcsec_gss_krb5` module (in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, after which you need a restart).

Comment: I've done this, and it still hangs (and reports the upcall failed issue).

Comment: try to run rpc.gssd by hand. On RHEL systems you need additionally SECURE_NFS="yes". May be it's not required for ubuntu as well.

Comment: I don't need kerberos - is it possible to disable? I just ran rpc.gssd (it's running is the ps list) and it still hangs.

Comment: how did you solve this in the end?

Comment: sadly, never solved it. Ended up going with a non-NFS solution.